# In bash how do I count the occurence of each word in a set, in multiple files

Tags: bash

I have a big list of words (>1000) which are actually filenames and a directory with a lot of source code files (>2000). I want , for each word(filename) in the list, to count its total occurences in all the files of the directory. What I currently do is:

```
#!/bin/sh
SEARCHPATH=$1
for var in "${@:2}"
do
    BASE=$( basename "$var" )
    COUNT=$(grep -o "$BASE" $SEARCHPATH/* | wc -l)
    echo -e "$BASE:" " $COUNT"
done
```

which works but is inefficient because for each word it searches the whole directory, and the words are too many. I am looking for a solution that scans the directory once, accumulating the word count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all your words in a file. Then you can try this:

```
grep -ohFf wordsFile path/* | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: Works but it does not report the words not found at all. I guess an ugly hack is to concatenate the original list before sort and uniq and know that every result should be interpreted with -1 count

Comment: Well, if you have two files containing words, you can find which words are not present in one of them by using `comm`, for example. This will need to be an extra step though.